# Is there a way to implement arbitrary matrix multipication in renderscript?

Tags: android, matrix, renderscript

is there way to implement in renderscript multiplication of any matrices witn mxn and nxp?
From the default packages I find out just a hardcoded implementation for a multiply of matrices with sizes 4x4, 3x3, 2x2.

Here is the definition : http://developer.android.com/reference/renderscript/rs__types_8rsh_source.html
Here the implementation : https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/40545939/

Im novice to RenderScript, but from the way how types are defined looks to me not possible. Also if Allocation is used, then all examples I saw are always having equal inAllocation and outAllocation, equal by the vector(arrays) sizes.

Maybe someone can have some idea on this?

Edit:

As Tim was saying I started with using 2 input allocations and one output set directly.

```
rs_allocation gInA;
rs_allocation gInB;
rs_allocation gOut;
rs_script gScript;

void root( *v_out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
// for every x, y on the out matrix calculate the multiply
// exp if x=y=1 do calc for row 1 from gInA and column 1 from gInB
// but what are the sizes from this matrices, or we also need to set // dose as variable?
}

void calculate() {
   // how we can call for each x, y of the predefined gOutMatrix?
    rsForEach(gOut, NULL);
}
```

Maybe small code snipett would be nice from your side. 
Tnx, Blaze

Answer (score 1):

the easy way would be to use only the output Allocation and use `getElementAt_<type>` to read from the input Allocations of a different size.

I'm curious--if we were to add this as an intrinsic, do you specifically need only GEMM, or are there other BLAS operations you'd like supported?

Comment: Hi Tim, well to be ones I have not work with graphics for a long time. But I do found it hard to believe that this kind of stuff are not intrinsic, all other frameworks-languages have this by default(Used to work a lot with Matlab). Aside of this, I also find it hard for self implement. Like you are saying I started with using 2 input allocations set directly. Please check the bug, I made a update. Tnx